# Outlook calendar: Cancelling reminders for some appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook calendar at work (Professional Plus 2010). I get reminders for meetings which is nice, but there are some meetings that I don't want to get reminders to. How can I cancel reminders to specific meetings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Outlook, you open the meeting you want to delete the reminder for (or the series of meetings, if it's recurrent) and then click next to the bell icon on the amount of minutes and choose none. This answer was found using the help of: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Set-or-remove-reminders-f6e5ff7c-6971-4f58-a073-eda2b91884e9